# How to create list of all available resources for Laravel api?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, rest, laravel-5, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on a Laravel api in localhost.    How do I create a route that lists everything available in a resource like the WordPress api does here http://example.com/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2?

Research shows that I can use the command php artisan routes to get a list of routes but how do I make this available to a user as an endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Route::getRoutes()` method to get all routing data.

Just loop through the routes and use `->getPath()` to generate the list of paths.

For all other properties take a look at the API at: https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is this useul api document generator https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator